# How can I slice an int array by stride in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, slice, stride

I am learning Java.

In Python, I can:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
my_new_list = my_list [::-1]
print my_new_list                # [4,3,2,1]
```

Is there any method I can use in Java to do that on int array?

Edit1: Sorry for the bad example. How about my_list [::-2]?

Edit2: What I mean my_list [::-2] is like

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
my_new_list = my_list [::-2]
print my_new_list                # [4,2]
```

Edit3: Slicing by stride in Python is to "check" the item in a list every step (stride).If the step is negative, Python would check the item from the end of the list to the beginning of the list. For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
my_list1 = my_list[::2]       # my_list1 becomes [1,3,5,7,9]
my_list2 = my_list[::3]       # my_list2 becomes [1,4,7]
my_list3 = my_list[::4]       # my_list3 becomes [1,5,9]
my_list4 = my_list[::-3]      # my_list4 becomes [9,6,3]
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for the method. How about just slicing by stride? like my_list [::-2]

Comment: That is a separate question - please describe your **full** question when posting, not _part_ of it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am so sorry for the confusing example

Comment: Further, not all Java developers speak Python - please describe the problem, the input and the expected output.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry for that, I will edit soon.

Comment: @JayWong and what is your desired output after my_list [::-2]?

Comment: As this is a Q&A site, the primary goal of any question should be future usefulness - sorry to be annoying; but in order for a question to be a good question it should contain all relevant information for a future user reading it...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I see. I was too naive and not responsible.

Comment: @OAD The new list would become [4,2], sorry for the missing information.

Comment: @JayWong will you tell us in simple language how this output is coming, like is this coming checking even numbers of alternate values?

Comment: @OAD Yes, I have edited my question. I thought it was a common feature among programming languages, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not have something builtin what you want, but you can built your own logic for it, something like this, just put the value in `val` , for example my_list[::2] 2 in this case `val` will be `2`

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
int ml[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int val = -2;
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
if(val>0){
for(int i = 0 ; i<ml.length;i+=val){
    al.add(ml[i]);
}
}
else if(val<0){
for(int i = ml.length-1 ;  i>=0; i+=val){
    al.add(ml[i]);
}   

}


for(int i = 0 ; i<al.size();i++){
    System.out.println(al.get(i));
}

}
```

Comment: @JayWong this code is a mess - I would not use it. You would be better off with a smart `Iterator` design to create a "view" of the underlying data.

Comment: I would appreciate if you provide him a better solution rather by telling him how to do, he is newbie in java.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the array to list then use `Collections.reverse()` on that list.

```
Integer a[]={1,2,3,4};
List <Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a);
System.out.println(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/vHufk4)

Comment: I am sorry for the misleading example, can I do something like my_list [::-2]?

Comment: @JayWong can you explain more about the output

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following way, with the help of [`Collections#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and for using that method we first have to convert array to list and after reversing the list we will again convert it to array. You *should* better use `List` instead of array if *possible*.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        arr = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this in Java 8

```
int a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int step = -2;

int b = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
            .filter(i -> i%step == 0)
            .map(i -> a[(step < 0) ? a.length-i-1 : i])
            .toArray();
```

It should work with all example arrays and steps you provided.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has an utility method for that:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```